# Ubuntu Virtual Desktop for web development

Tags: lubuntu, remote-desktop, vdi, virtualdesktop

I installed Ubuntu Desktop, LUbuntu for web development in a VMWARE Esxi.
I set 1 GB ram for 3 operating systems which my friends are going to use with me.
The server is 8 core processor 32 bit with 16 GB RAM.

First of all, I installed XRDP for remote access of these virtual machines which really sucked.
Later installed GNOME in these Ubuntu's and accessed remote desktop which was also slow.
Later installed XFCE which also was slow.

I have installed apache, mysql, PHP for web development. In the case of IDE we use Aptana and Notepad++.

Can you please suggest me a good remote desktop solution in Ubuntu.
Also, please suggest me a minimum linux distro which would run in very less RAM say - 256 MB.
So, If I give load using the IDEs, PHP, MYSQL and apache would work on 1 to 2 GB RAM.

As far as my research on internet ubuntu or linux distros do not have good VDI(Virtual Desktop infrastructure )solution or Desktop as a Service in LINUX which could be remotely accessed.

Please give me your inputs. Or may I have to put myself back to windows.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've been through the whole RDP, XRDP, VNC, Chrome Remote headaches.

I don't know why this isn't more well-known, but I use:

NoMachine
https://www.nomachine.com/

Also, read up on
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_technology

NoMachine listens on port 4000 so make sure it's open.